# Will I look bad if I apply for the same job twice?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, applications

I have sent a cover letter and CV to this job, do you think they will notice if I apply on the site as well?

Comment: Where you sent the cover letter and CV to? What are your reasons for applying twice to the same job, via different means?

Comment: Are you saying that you're applying through a job aggregator and then through the main company website?

Comment: How big is this company?  The company in my answer below is huge... which both means bureaucracy and "lots of jobs".

Comment: The answer may be different if the first application is through a third-party recruiter (who may or may not have actually sent your application through to the company, and the company may or may not prefer to receive an application directly, to avoid having to pay the recruiter).

Answer (score 3):

> I have sent a cover letter and CV to this job, do you think they will
>   notice if I apply on the site as well?

**Yes, I do think they will notice.**

As a hiring manager, I got all cover letters and CVs from applicants who were qualified. And I also got forwarded all online applications. I always notice when I got the same applicant more than once.

Now, you may actually be asking "Will it help if I apply both via paper and via online?" The answer to that is almost certainly No. Applying through multiple channels is very unlikely to give you any advantage.

And you may actually be asking "Will the employer dislike if I apply via paper and online?" The answer to that is Maybe. It annoyed me whenever I got multiple applications from the same applicant - without regard to the channel in which they were received. I tried hard not to let that annoyance color my scrutiny of the application, but I'd be lying if I said I could avoid it completely.

Apply through one channel. That should be enough.

Comment: I would just like to add, where I live, nearly every employer that I've dealt with wants a paper application even if you applied online. I don't understand the need, other than they are still stuck in some paper trail stone age.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is no, as one of HR's usual processes is to weed out the obvious stuff such as unqualified candidates, ineligible candidates, and duplicate submissions.

There would be a problem if you submitted for this position individually and a recruiting agency submitted on your behalf, as employers do not like to get into disagreements with recruiters over whether the employer owes a referral fee or not.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> do you think they will notice if I apply on the site as well?

Most likely they will, if their recruiting and screening process are adequate.

I don't think that this will directly harm you or make you look "bad"; **if they find you are good candidate they will contact you regardless of the means you applied by.**

Just, be careful not to cross the thin like and start spamming them in all the possible ways to apply. Applying in *just one way* should be sufficient. If you have no good reasons for applying in both then I'd suggest you stick to one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm involved in this sort of thing (pre-screening and third level interviews) and with us you **MUST ALSO** apply online.

Even if you hand your CV to me, even if I scan it into the system, even if I like you and strongly think you should make it to the next stage, without whatever the online system does there's NO GO.

We've got little cards we hand out detailing this but I also stress it face to face.

So imho at worst it won't hurt, at best you really should.